# Is "blink at" a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

There's an English paper saying "blink at = show surprise", and "blink at" is a phrasal verb. I've searched a lot of places and didn't see any saying the same thing. Is this true? Does anyone know? Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: A search will quickly answer your question.  Then you can answer your own question and educate us all!

Comment: Give some sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A phrasal verb is made up of two or more words ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/vocabulary-phrasal-verbs-1210338)). Phrasal verbs attain a meaning that is distinct from taking the literal meaning of each word and combining them. For example:

> I turn on the TV

*Turn on* is a phrasal verb meaning to activate. It has its own dictionary entry ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20on)). It doesn't mean literally to *turn* | *on the TV*, as if one is turning relative to the TV. In a sense, phrasal verbs often form from transferred or figurative senses of verb and particle or verb and preposition combinations.

In the case of *blink at*, it can qualify as a phrasal verb. As a phrasal verb, according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/blink), it means:

> (blink at) [usually with negative] React to (something) with surprise or disapproval.
>
> ‘he doesn't blink at the unsavoury aspects of his subject’

In this context, *blink at* has lost the literal sense of blinking in the direction of someone. If I said,

> I blinked at you, but you didn't notice.

That's not a phrasal verb, but a verb and a prepositional phrase describing direction. I literally shut and opened by eyes. Where? In your direction. Similarly, "I didn't blink at you" would describe me not shutting my eyes. Where? At you. However, if I said,

> I don't even blink at my colleagues' behavior anymore. Nothing could surprise me.

That's a phrasal verb, because *blinked at* together conveys a meaning idiomatic and distinct from the two words separately. I am not *surprised*. The state of literally blinking is irrelevant to the meaning, except in a residual or figurative sense that people who blink are surprised; I don't blink; therefore I'm not surprised. The usage is habitual enough that the logic chain doesn't need to be invoked to understand the usage, just like one does not need to logic out other phrasal verbs. Someone reading this as an admission of not shutting their eyes would be in error.

Comment: Is _blink at_ really non-compositional, though? Blinking is a natural physical response to receiving a shock, just like jumping is. Is “He blinked at the sudden flash of light” literal or non-literal? I’d say the connection is fluid and close enough that there’s no need to consider _blink at_ a phrasal verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, and turning a knob was how many TV sets were activated in olden times. Now we don't have to literally blink to have our expression of surprise described as "blinking at" something, and we don't have to literally turn a knob to "turn on" the TV (or our romantic partner).

Comment: Of course it's even less literal since we normally talk about things we "don't blink at" and not so much about things we did blink at.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is no doubt that _turn on_ is a phrasal verb, however, since only phrasal verbs – more specifically, only transitive _particle_ verbs – allow shifting. If _blink at_ is to be seen as a phrasal verb, it’s a prepositional verb, so only compositionality distinguishes phrasal from non-phrasal. Turning a knob is far enough removed from turning someone on sexually that compositionality is hard to argue for, especially because when turning on a tv or a partner, you were never at any point actually turning the tv or the partner. You were turning a knob (or similar).

Comment: With _blink at_, on the other hand, the difference is only that between “blink one’s eyes in surprise” and “be surprised (with or without actually blinking one’s eyes)”. The two are so closely related that it’s hardly possible to draw a line between them. Of course, we don’t _have_ to actually blink our eyes in order to blink at something, but it is hinted at in the expression. “He didn’t so much as blink at her gaudy dress” strongly implies to me that you’d have expected him to (literally) blink in astonishment or disapproval. The fact that it’s usually negated makes it _more_ literal.

Comment: I don't follow the objection. Shrugging is a natural response to treating something as if it's not important, but "shrug off" is a phrasal verb. Walking is a natural mode of leaving someone, but *walk off* is a phrasal verb. Driving has a clear directional sense already, but *drive at* is a phrasal verb. Do you see what I'm *driving at*? ;) I agree that *blink at* has many cases where it is compositional, but composition doesn't always work with the surprise meaning. Someone who "doesn't blink at any challenge" naturally blinks from time to time. The absence of eye-shutting is not implied.

Comment: I think it's just that *phrasal verb* is at best a heterogenous category. *Blink* can perfectly well have the same non-literal meaning without *at*, but generally it doesn't - in most cases where it is used without *at*, it has a different meaning (*they blinked as they came out into the sunlight*; *Iran didn't blink*), and in most cases where it refers to surprise, it is used with *at*. That is something that a good dictionary ought to point out, so if we're not going to give it its own entry on the basis that it's a *phrasal verb*, I think we need a new label.

Comment: I think there's a lot of sense in what Janus says, and would rather have a more rational set of labels and categories, but you have to work with what you've got.